# Restangular equivalent in Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-upgrade

I am looking into migrating our application from angularjs (1.6.x) to modern Angular.

One thing I am not finding is a recommended replacement for [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) (I am most interested in the generic response interceptor feature, where all my application's REST requests could hook into some base response handlers, along with specific ones).

I am curious if others have found something, or if Angular's HttpClient itself accomplishes the same goals now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this library will cover features of Restangular in Angular 2+

[Ngx-restangular](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular/)

Comment: Oof, bad googling on my part. Thank you